# JQuery works only on firefox and not in any other web browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I invoked a button click event by checking if enter key is pressed by onkeydown event for a asp textbox. I used jquery to invoke the c# function. It works fine for mozilla firefox only and not working in any other web browsers after deployed to server. Do I need to upgrade?

Comment: Post the relevant code

Comment: Yes, for Stack Overflow users to provide you with helpful information you must [ask a well formed question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).